# Org-mode default mouse-3 behavior overrides keybinding I've defined each time I revert a buffer

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings

I've bound the mouse-3 to a custom function, with a statement

```
(define-key org-mode-map [mouse-3] 'foobar)
```

But when I revert some .org file, the keybinding of the mouse-3 goes back to the default and it displays the context menu.

I have this problem every time I start up emacs too. The init file loads, but the mouse-3 won't run the custom function I assigned for the org-mode in org-mode buffers. And when I eval-buffer the init file, it gets fixed until I revert those buffers.

Answer (score -1):

What is the value of variable `revert-buffer-function`? If it doesn't do what you want, set the variable (in that mode) to your own function that does.

Comment: C-h v says its value is revert-buffer--default. Is it something I can change without messing up important stuff?

Comment: Yes. Don't change `revert-buffer-default`. Just bind `revert-buffer-function` (locally - in that mode only) to a function that does what you want (e.g., first calls `revert-buffer-default` and then binds the keys you want).

Comment: @Drew But why would `revert-buffer` override the bindings?

Comment: @KaushalModi: I don't know that it does. But apparently the bindings are being reset. `revert-buffer-default` runs hooks `before-revert-hook` and `after-revert-hook`, and it can invoke `revert-buffer-insert-file-contents-function`. It's trivial to try what I suggested and see whether it takes care of the problem.

Comment: No idea why someone would downvote this. Oh well.